# How to write string from EditControl to a text file in Visual Studio 2008 , using the "Save To.." dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc, file-io, savefiledialog

I'm writing my first app in MFC, and I was looking to include a very simple feature : Include a "Save To File" button that on being clicked will bring up the familiar "Save As.." Dialog box and will ultimately save the data  in a text file. I couldn't find how to invoke this dialog box - can someone just point me at the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is CFileDialog :

```
CFileDialog d(FALSE);
if(IDOK == d.DoModal())
{
    CString sFileName = dlg.GetPathName();

    // ... Save your text to the file

}
```

There are many parameters in the CFileDialog constructor that you can change to affect how the dialog behaves, check the MSDN documentation for details.

Comment: So, do I have to make a CFileDialog object as a member of my class, or can I put the entire declaration and usage under the OnBtnClicked() Event Handler?

Comment: You can just declare and use it in your event handler.

Comment: Got what I was looking for : http://funnotes.net/File-open-dialog-box-using-CFileDialog.php

Answer (score 1):

For what you've described, you should probably just use a `CEditView` instead of writing your own code. It's pre-written, tested, etc.

For most other situations, you should realize that MFC itself normally handles the details of creating the `Save As...` dialog and such, so all you normally have to do is put code into your document class' `Serialize()` member function to read and write your document's data. That's passed a reference to `CArchive` object, so all you have to deal with is writing or reading the data for your document object.

Comment: I looked at CEditView, and I guess that it has a lot of functionality that I'm not looking for - I have a EditControl in my dialog box, whose contents I want to save when the user clicks the "Save As" Button. I found a class (SaveFileDialog) which could potentially solve my problem, but I'm not able to find a good example on the web that shows how to use this. I don't have a MFC book , so google is all I've got !! 
I told you this since from your response, u look someone very experienced with MFC, and could maybe point me at such an example. Thanks !!